# request.getParameter needs to edit

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts

In my struts execute method I am getting one value from  UI through request.getParameter(). Inside execute() I wants to edit requestParameter.

request.getParameter("STATE") , Is there any option to edit STATE from java side.

Comment: Why do you need to edit the **parameter**? Get its value into your local variable, and do anything you want with it.

Comment: this request object is sending to another layer. I cant touch the code there.

Comment: you mean you want to overwrite the value of the "STATE" parameter in your application?

Comment: Yes I need to overwite @ramp

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [HttpServletRequestWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)
for this purpose. You pass the original request to the wrapper from either a filter or a servlet and override the request methods you wish to. To the rest of the application, you pass the modified wrapper object than the original request.

```
public class WrapperRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {


        public WrapperRequest (ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest)request);
        }


        public String getParameter(String paramName) {
            String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
            if ("yourParamName".equals(paramName)) {
                value = "yourValue";
            }
            return value;
        }

        public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
        //override here too
        }
    }
```

Then in your filter or servlet

```
WrapperRequest wrapperReq= new WrapperRequest(request);
chain.doFilter(wrapperReq,respone); //for filters, all resources in the request will see the new param value
requestDispatcher.forward(wrapperReq, response);//servlets, the forwarded resource will see the new param value
```

Comment: I will try this